# How To Add A Script To Add Functionality To the Terminal?

Tags: macos, perl, command-line

I have a small perl script ( found [here](https://github.com/egonSchiele/Command-Line-Coda) ) which adds command line functionality to an application I already have installed, Coda.  Basically it will open a file with the application when I type:

```
coda filename.py
```

Where (on OSX) do I need to put this file to make it function?  Do I need to do anything else to my environment to get this working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Type `echo $PATH` at the terminal.  You will get back a series of paths separated by colons.  The file needs to be placed into one of those folders.  The file also needs to have the execute flag set, which is done with the `chmod` tool.

Comment: Also, wouldn't you need to put `#!/path/to/coda` at the top? Unless there's something about Mac OSX that works differently from other Unixen?

Comment: `coda` is a script written in perl that accesses a bundled osx .app program, it already contains the appropriate `#!/usr/bin/env perl` at the top, all DorkRawk needs to do is install it into the path and mark it as executable.

Comment: Yep, it works fine with the #!/usr/bin/env perl at the top.  Thanks for the help, everybody.